# Accessing pseudo properties with Groovy 4.x throws a MissingPropertyException

Tags: groovy

When I try to access the `activated` pseudo property on the following class, I get a `MissingPropertyException` on Groovy 4.x:

```
@Test
void beanPropertiesTest() {
   assert new User().activated // Fails
}

class User {

    Boolean isActivated() {
        return true
    }
}
```

The code works fine on Groovy 3.x though. Is there an AST annotation or compiler flag that I need to set?

I'm on Java 17.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching, I believe I have found that the solution is to change the return type from `Boolean` to `boolean`. The [4.0.0 change log](https://groovy-lang.org/changelogs/changelog-4.0.0.html) referenced [this JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6097) with [this comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-10708?focusedCommentId=17572404&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-17572404) from Eric Miles:

> An “is” method that returns any other type is not a property accessor.

Further reading revealed that by "any other type" he meant any other type than the primitive `boolean`, as further explained by Paul King [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9382?focusedCommentId=17030113&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-17030113).

The following pull request on GitHub cemented the change to prefer `isName()` over `getName()` for `boolean` accessors:

[GROOVY-9382, GROOVY-10133: prefer isName() over getName() for boolean](https://github.com/apache/groovy/pull/1599)

`Boolean` accessors will now have to use `getName()` to properly align it with the [JavaBean specification](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) (See: Introspection 8.3.2).